# How to symbolize line jumps/crosses in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, geometry, representation

Where two line features cross but are not physically connected (or related), I would like to symbolize the crossing using a line jump symbol. [Visio is capable is using such symbology](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-line-jumps-for-connectors-1a5516db-0212-4352-90dd-fc9cfd4018ed):

[image]

In 2008, Esri said ["we might get this on the list of enhancements for future releases."](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=179) I've seen no update to indicate that the enhancement was ever made.

Are line jumps possible in ArcMap today, either natively or via a workaround? If you've employed a workaround, what is it?

**EDIT 3/7/2016: I would like to do this without modifying the underlying geometry, if possible.**

Comment: Haven't done myself, but should be possible with http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm

Comment: You will be able to use representations for this if you have the higher level ArcGIS (Standard and Advacned) licenses:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//008t00000002000000.htm

Comment: @DrewSmith I think representations are probably the best answer. If you were to rewrite this as an answer, I'd probably accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have either an ArcGIS Standard or Advanced license you can use representations to visually modify  how your data displays without modifying the underlying geometry.

Here is a description from the ArcGIS Help:
 "Representations allow you to customize the appearance of features by storing symbol information with the feature geometry inside feature classes. This additional control can help you meet stringent cartographic specifications or simply improve the display. Representations are a property of a feature class that are stored in system tables inside the geodatabase and in the feature class itself. A feature class can have more than one representation associated with it, allowing the same data to be displayed uniquely on different map products."

Answer (score 2):

ESRI has released [Water Network Editing toolbar](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/tools/overview-network-editing-tools/) which they describe as:

> The Water Utility Network Editing toolbar is a series of tools to improve a map technician's editing infrastructure data experience.

[image]

Comment: We use the Water Network Editing toolbar and the Create Over/Under Jump tools work really well.  You can configure the tool to use the specific radius you require (the default I believe is 7ft, we have ours set to 0.5m)

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. I should've been clear that I don't want to modify the underlying geometry, though. I will modify the question to be clear about that. Thanks.